# How to place a TextView and an ImageView on a row?

Tags: android

I place a TextView and an ImageView on a row, normally the ImageView should close to the right of the TextView, the both should be seen always. But when the TextView has too much words, the ImageView will be crowded out of the LinearLayout. BTW I only want display text one line in TextView if it has too much words, the rest words can be replace with '..' postfix. Any idea for my problem? Thanks!

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/device_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="MacBookMacBookMacBookMacBookMacBookMacBookMacBook"
            android:textColor="#FF1D202C"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/device_online_state"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/sr_icon_device_online"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

---

Finally, I find the solution, here is the code as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="12345678901234567000000000000000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Give your textview a specific width then add

```
 android:ellipsize="end" 
 android:maxLines="1"
```

If still you have doubts then please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you! but don't forget the ImageView, it will be crowded out of the right edge of the container view.

Comment: @sunjinbo i think you should place imageview first then textview. Next give your textview a specific width, ellipsize = end and set maxline = 1; Still you have doubts then do let me know i can share a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You should add the ellipsize property to your TextView to get the `...` effect with

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: but how to display the both view always in LinearLayout or other container?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the text with a `LinearLayout` and set its width to 0dp, and its weight to 1:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Edit: Using the weight attribute will allow the linear layout to adpat to other views's width.

Comment: Thanks! But if the textview has a few words, the both view has a big blank margin between them. :(

Comment: @sunjinbo this how it suppose to be. White space b/w text and image is ok.

Answer (score 0):

- Limit the TextView to one line
- Add `android:ellipsize="end"`
- And use weights to limit it. No need for the extra `LinearLayout`

Then add weight for it to make it take the remaining space after the image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! And I have a try your solution, if the TextView has too much words, This is ok. But if it has a few words, the ImageView still be layout on the right of the container view., the both view has a big margin between them.

Comment: It's seem that the textview's layout_width should be set to "wrap_content".